# Couple foreignKey reference a table with couple PrimaryKey

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[NSID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Pk_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([RegionCode] ASC,  [ID_N] ASC)
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
[Reference][nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NULL,
[Customer_ID_N] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Reference] ASC)
)
```

I want to  put (CustomemrID_N,RegionCode) as a Foreign Key reference to the Customer table.

```
  Alter table [dbo].[Order]
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Customer FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID_N,RegionCode)
  REFERENCES[dbo].[Customer](ID_N,RegionCode)
```

but i get this error :

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Customer' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Order_Customer'.

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag, as this is clearly SQL Server, due to the refernece to the `dbo` schema in the error.

Comment: The above is also riddled with lots of other typographical errors. Both your `CREATE` statements are missing a right parenthesis (`)`) at the end. There is no column `Reference` in your table `Order` (which is a terrible name for an object, as `ORDER` is a reserved keyword), but you define `Reference` as the PK. There is no space between `Customer` and `FOREIGN` in `ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_CustomerFOREIGN KEY`. I'm voting to close this as typographical/not reproducible, because that's all these are.

Comment: Also, there is no column `Customer_ID_N` in your table `Order`, so the error message would not produce that error. Considering all the other typographical error, I don't doubt that what you have given us above is not your real SQL at all.

Comment: Those tables contains lot of columns i just give u whre i get the bug, the customer_ID_N exist in the table Order .

Comment: And if we run your statements, we don't get the error you state, @nada , because none of the statements are valid syntax. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b39002e82b60cc01b3c0ef6c2af7d3e). If you're going to minimise your code, make sure it's still valid code.

Comment: I edit it, i forget to put the Reference as a column .. can u tel me if it s okey plz

Comment: That's still not valid SQL, @nada .

Comment: I  edit it again im sure this time it good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many problems with your attempt... Most are typographical.

Firstly this statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[NSID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Pk_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([RegionCode] ASC,  [ID_N] ASC)
```

This is missing a right parenthesis (`)`) at the end of the statement.

Then the next statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
[Reference][nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NULL,
[Customer_ID_N] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Reference] ASC)
```

This too, isn't valid, there is also a missing right parenthesis.

Your last statement is also, not valid:

```sql
  Alter table [dbo].[Order]
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_CustomerFOREIGN KEY ([Customer_ID_N],RegionCode)
  REFERENCES[dbo].[Customer](ID_N,RegionCode)
```

`CONSTRAINT FK_Order_CustomerFOREIGN KEY` should be `CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Customer FOREIGN KEY`; notice the space between `FK_Order_Customer` and `FOREIGN.

Once we fix that we get yet something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[NSID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Pk_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([RegionCode] ASC,  [ID_N] ASC))
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
[Reference][nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID_N] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[RegionCode] [varchar](1) NULL,
[Customer_ID_N] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Reference] ASC))
GO
  Alter table [dbo].[Order]
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Customer FOREIGN KEY ([Customer_ID_N],RegionCode)
  REFERENCES[dbo].[Customer](ID_N,RegionCode)
```

Note, when you run that, you get the error you have above. That's because your PK is defined as `[RegionCode] ASC,  [ID_N] ASC` **not** `ID_N,RegionCode`. So let's fix that as swap the foreign key around...

```sql
  Alter table [dbo].[Order]
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Customer FOREIGN KEY (RegionCode,[Customer_ID_N])
  REFERENCES[dbo].[Customer](RegionCode, ID_N)
```

And now it works.

Address the typographical errors, then read the error; it was telling you the problem.

Comment: I understand now...Many thanks for ur answers and time to edit comment my code.